# Background image not showing with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've tried multiple different ways but none displayed the image as background.

CSS

```
.spec{
        background: url('white_logo_red_font.jpg');
        height: 100px;
        width: 150px;
      }
```

HTML

```
<div class="spec">
    hi
</div>
```

The image is in the same folder so the url is correct. I've also tried `background-image` instead of `background`.

**Edit**: image location

index.js is where the code is.

[image]

Comment: what is the div dimensions, and you can check in chrome -> dev tools -> network if the image is sent, maybe your server not provide images the same way

Comment: It seems there aren't errors. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: maybe your image is big and on white background. so inside this div you will see only cropped top left 100x150 white nothing. code is OK,but show your css include (full html)

Comment: Add a screenshot of your files in their directory (folder location).

Answer (score 1):

That is probably caused by the wrong image path.

Try using link from the web, for example: `background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/350x150')` the image should be displayed - that means that your css syntax is fine.

Then fix your path, you probably have to add `'./'`, `'/images/'`, `'../images/`' before "white_logo..." the image path have to be relative to the `css` file.

Comment: The path is correct, the image is in the same directory. The web url did work and the image was shown. I've edited the post to include the directory where everything s

Comment: If the web url worked the path has to be wrong. You have included a SS without location of the css file and relative location to the image have to be relative to outputed css file (not html file) and you don't have css or sass file in views catalog. You can inspect that div and check where you relative path leads to and fix it accordingly. Also if you don't use '/' before the name of the image in some cases it can work on www.domain.com but not on www.domain.com/page - because it is relative to the domain.

Comment: Okay, so I noticed something: I get 404 for when I include it locally (from a file in the same directory) in the Run terminal. The **same thing happens** when I try to `src="somethinglocal"`. Does it have to do with NodeJS? Maybe with `app.use` I need to include?

Answer (score 0):

try,
CSS

```
.spec{
        background: url('../white_logo_red_font.jpg');
        height: 100px;
        width: 150px;
      }
```

HTML

```
<div class="spec">
    hi
</div>
```

Comment: I get a "cannot resolve file ... " error (this way the path is wrong because the image is in the same directory)

Answer (score -2):

I have noticed that there is something wring with the background image url **`background: url('white_logo_red_font.jpg');`** use correct url.

You can try my code.

```css
.spec {
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578163246111-e02c555d00e1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80);
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="spec">
    hi
</div>
```

Comment: Relative paths are allowed in `url()`. In fact most sites use relative paths in styles, if they didn't styles would have to be updated with each domain change.

Comment: You didn't answer the question and you are suggesting that `white_logo_red_font.jpg` is not correct url - but it is.

Comment: @Deykun I can see your answer is similar to my answer.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.