# Getting 404 for local files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently posted [Background image not showing with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603527/background-image-not-showing-with-css/59603566?noredirect=1#comment105386105_59603566) and thought it has to be something with the url I included even though I was sure it was correct (they were in the same directory so it was straightforward). I wasn't able to resolve that issue and now, I face the same issue but for a .js file.

Picture of work space:

[image]

Picture of the Run prompt:

[image]
     .

In `app.js` I do have `require('./like_button');`. I am new to using these technologies, I must be missing something general...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to serve the static file from a specific folder. In your case `views`.

Add this line where you've declared your **app**.

```js
app.use(express.static('views'))
```

For more reference check out

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html